# Modelling elastic collisions and reflection from wall in 1D box of two particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision, simulations

I have a very simple system of two particles. Particle $A$ and particle $B$. Particle $A$ is acted by constant potential along wall $C$ while no potential is acted on particle $B$. If they both initially are at rest, both have same masses and collision are perfectly elastic, then how do I find the position of particles at given any time?

[image]

For special case, assuming the particles have no volume, if both particles collide at wall C, then it can be modeled as single particle using center of mass acting on potential of half. The motion keeps repeating and repeating. I only have to calculate in which interval they collide.

How to model this problem in general? Especially after particle $B$ strikes wall. It seems like the particle is moving through center of mass under half it's potential and gets it's velocity decreased suddenly (twice).

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by
"Particle A is acted by constant potential along wall C while no potential is acted on particle B".
A constant potential applies no force since the derivative of a constant is zero. Could you clarify this? Also, what does "along wall C" mean?

Comment: @Asaf you can assume particle A is constantly accelerating towards wall C while particle B just sits in there (no acceleration) just colliding elastically with particle A and wall C.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to generalize this setup?

Comment: I am not sure particle A would ever reach the wall, particle A is like a heavy piston pressing down on ideal gas (represented by a single particle B) confined under it; I think the solution should be some kind of periodic motion.

Comment: @MaximUmansky the problem is isomorphic to a ball on a tilted triangular billiard board (two directions are two particles' positions). Its motion is not necessarily periodic.

Comment: @Ruslan Sure, in general not periodic here; periodic is not the right word, I meant "recurring" motion; but my main point was that particle A cannot reach the wall C, contrary to the statement of the problem "both particles collide at wall C"

Comment: @MaximUmansky well one can make up such initial conditions that they do collide at the wall. I guess such a triple collision has undefined results in this model.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote up a quick MATLAB simulation of your problem ([copied here](http://pastebin.com/NagvW3G5)). I assumed that a constant potential at C means that the wall is held at a constant electrical potential, meaning that A is a charged particle and B is not. An infinitely large wall at constant potential results in a constant electric field everywhere, so A accelerates towards the wall with constant acceleration. That's a simple situation, so I used that. I also assumed A collides with B elastically and B collides with the wall elastically. Finally, A and B have zero volume.

The simulation takes small steps in time and updates the particles position under constant acceleration (0 in the case of B). When the particles collide or when B collides with the wall, their velocities are updated according to conservation of momentum and kinetic energy.

Here is a plot of the positions of A and B over time where A and B have the same mass and B starts halfway between A and the wall:
[image: equal masses]

This is pretty chaotic motion. However, certain starting conditions result in rather orderly motion. Here is a plot where $m_B = 0.655 m_A$:
[image: mb = .655ma]

I'm not sure if this is an artifact of using discrete steps in the simulation, but smaller step sizes do not change the result.

A different starting position will also result in vastly different motion. Here are equal mass A and B but with B starting much closer to A:
[image]

If you're trying to find the interval between bounces, I don't believe you will find any sort of nice expression. The bounce period is chaotic and irregular aside from some special initial conditions.

Comment: Why do you need to do numerics at all (if not just for the fun of it)? This problem is solvable exactly for each time segment between collisions (A moves ballistically and B is free). Collisions are also tractable analytically via conservation of energy and momentum. Then you wouldn't need to doubt in validity of your discrete steps.

Comment: @Ruslan: The numerics are needed to determine when collisions occur. For constant-size time steps, it is unknown whether A and B collide or B hits the wall until the coordinates are checked (lines 28-38 in the linked code, which are also the exact solutions from momentum and kinetic energy conservation). I could write a more complicated program to determine whether an A-B collision or a B-wall collision would happen first and then simulate exactly to that point, but that would be more work than I felt like doing for this question.

Comment: although I have not asked in question, is it statistically possible to estimate the average time in collision for long time?

Comment: @MulaKoSaag You could possible use my code to run a bunch of simulations with different masses and starting positions and get some empirical relations. I don't see a way of getting an answer out of the equations, especially if you want varying masses of A and B and different starting positions.

Answer (score 2):

Particle $A$ in homogeneous field $U=-Fx$ feels the force $F$. Thus between collisions its acceleration due to the field is

$$a_A=\frac F {m_A}.\tag1$$

So we can describe its motion between collisions since time $t_i$ as

$$x_A=x_A^{(i)}+(t-t_i)v_A^{(i)}+\frac{a_A(t-t_i)^2}2,\tag2$$

where $x_A^{(i)}$ and $v_A^{(i)}$ are position and velocity of the particle at the moment of $i$th collision and $t_i$ is time of $i$th collision.
The particle $B$ is free between collisions:

$$x_B=x_B^{(i)}+(t-t_i)v_B^{(i)}.\tag3$$

Now equating $x_A=x_B$ we find when the particles could collide:

$$t=\frac{a_At_i-v_A^{(i)}+v_B^{(i)}\pm\sqrt{\left(v_A^{(i)}-v_B^{(i)}\right)^2+2a_A\left(x_B^{(i)}-x_A^{(i)}\right)}}{a_A}.\tag4$$

Here we should choose smallest of $t>t_i$.

Another possibility is collision of either particle with the wall. The particle $A$ would collide with the wall (which we place at $x=0$) at time determined from $x_A=0$:

$$t=\frac{a_At_i-v_A^{(i)}\pm\sqrt{\left(v_A^{(i)}\right)^2-2a_Ax_A^{(i)}}}{a_A}.\tag5$$

Here again we should choose smallest of $t>t_i$. For particle $B$ time of potential collision with the wall is

$$t=t_i-\frac{x^{(i)}}{v_B^{(i)}}.\tag6$$

Now we should compare the times of potential collisions found in $(4)$, $(5)$, $(6)$ and take the smallest of those satisfying $t>t_i$. This is the time of our $i+1$th collision. Computing $x_A$ and $x_B$ at this time $t_{i+1}$ will give us $x_A^{(i+1)}$ and $x_B^{(i+1)}$, from which we restart the computation.

The result will be piecewise-exact expression for the trajectories of the balls, a couple of which is shown in @MarkH's answer.

Note that this problem in general doesn't give periodic motion. We can see this by drawing the potential in configuration space of this system. If we take the energy of the system $E$ and consider points of collisions to be places with $U=U_0>E$, we'll have the following potential:

[image]

This looks quite like a triangular billiard table, tilted in the direction of one of the walls. Such system is not quite simple to make the ball perform periodic motion, and in general the paths the ball takes are chaotic.

Comment: Hi Ruslan, is it statistically possible to estimate the average time in collision for long time?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try computing average for several different time periods (longer than several collisions take), and I think these averages might converge to some value as time increases. Then just extrapolate it to infinite time.